# Loop through Multiple Listbox Controls And Check Selected Index Of Each

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using the below code to try and loop through all `ListBox` controls in a panel on a WinForm. I want to check if any of them have a `SelectedIndex` above 0. If they do, I want to set a boolean value in an array to `True`, else set it to `False`:

```
Dim i As Integer = -1
For Each cntrl As Control In Form1.Panel3.Controls
    If TypeOf cntrl Is ListBox Then
        i = i + 1
        If cntrl.selectedindex <> 0 Then
            ReportArray(i) = True
        Else
            ReportArray(i) = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The issue I am having is that `cntrl.selectedindex` is not valid as `.selectedindex` is being picked up that it is not a member of `Windows.Forms.Control`

How do I get this to see it as a `ListBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the cntrl to listbox first like this

```
Dim i As Integer = -1

For Each cntrl As Control In Form1.Panel3.Controls
    If TypeOf cntrl Is ListBox Then
        Dim TmpCntrl As ListBox = TryCast(cntrl, ListBox)

        i = i + 1
        If TmpCntrl.selectedindex <> 0 Then
            ReportArray(i) = True
        Else
            ReportArray(i) = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for that, was driving me crazy!